# Concat more than 2 strings

Tags: xslt, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate more than 2 strings in XSLT, is there a more convenient method than `concat(str1, concat(str2, str3))`?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat()` function takes multiple arguments:

```
concat(str1, str2, str3)
```

There's no need to nest multiple occurrences of the function.